# xamarin forms skiasharp batch processing images

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

it is possible to use skiasharp to batch process a list of images , I just want to datestamp all images without having to view every image.

```
    canvas.DrawText(text, xText, yText, textPaint);
    SKImage subimage = surface.Snapshot(); 
    //save fie
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes.  Write a function that date stamps an image, and then use a loop to process the batch of images.

Comment: I am using the surface.Snapshot() to snapshot the view and save to file , how can i do it without a view ? Thanks

Comment: you can create a `SKSurface` in memory, it doesn't have to be attached to a View

Comment: Yes ,I thought it would crashed , but it works . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by @jason the function can work without a view .